# El div se mueve al modificar el texto

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda, cuando el parrafo `<p>` del contenedor `class="pelicula"` pasa a ser de de un solo renglón, el `div` se baja, como puedo solucionarlo?

```css
.cartelera{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.pelicula{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.pelicula p{
    display: block;
}

.cartelera .pelicula img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 211px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="titulo">
            <img src="images/Logo cultura.png" alt="logo de cultura" class="logo">
            <h1>Cine Foro</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="cartelera">
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad de nuestro planeta se extingue</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad de nuestro planeta se extingue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

No se de que manera puedo editar el `css` para que no se me baje el `div`, o si tienen alguna otra idea de que mas puedo hacer sin usar `bootstrap` o alguna otra librería sería genial.

Gracias.

Comment: 1. Porque tienes 3 div de mismo nombre? 2. El css da siempre el mismo formato a todo los div Asi que el problema deberia estar en el css

Comment: Hola, hay 3 div con el mismo nombre debido a que queda como una cartelera de cine, cada uno trae una pelicula y un titulo diferente solo que para la consulta coloque 3 iguales como ejemplo.

Comment: lo único de tu css que me puede indicar que los divs se muevan es la propiedad margin que le estas poniendo a cada div de película, ten en cuenta que con la propiedad margin a secas, cada contenedor va a tener un margen en este caso de 30 pixeles tanto por arriba como por abajo y los laterales (en este caso nos estaríamos juntando con 60px de espaciado entre divs, 30 del primer div por el margin-bottom y otros 30 del segundo por el margin-top, y así sucesivamente), cuando añades un texto que ocupe distintas lineas, los divs adyacentes deberán moverse para seguir respetando esos 30px de margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes la propiedad vertical-align, aunque sería mejor si aprendes a usar flex: https://www.juanmacivico87.com/guia-flexbox/

```css
.cartelera{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.pelicula{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.pelicula p{
    display: block;
}

.cartelera .pelicula img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 211px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="titulo">
            <img src="images/Logo cultura.png" alt="logo de cultura" class="logo">
            <h1>Cine Foro</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="cartelera">
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad de nuestro planeta se extingue</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pelicula">
                <img src="images/Recurso_3.png" alt="">
                <p>La biodiversidad de nuestro planeta se extingue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esa es la solución que estaba buscando.